# Does Publ. Math. Institute Hung. have a new name?

Tags: journals, bibliography

Narrow question: Did Publ. Math. Institute Hung. (Publications of the Mathematical Institute of the Hungarian Academy of Sciences) change its name? I am finalizing the bibliography of an article in progress that refers to an article that supposedly appeared in Publ. Math. Institute Hung. (see e.g. [this MathSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535217/in-how-many-ways-can-a-permutation-cycle-be-decomposed-as-a-product-of-transposi)), but my go-to webpage for official journal abbreviations, https://mathscinet.ams.org/msnhtml/serials.pdf, appears to list no such journal. Perhaps it's now Acta Math. Hungar. or Period. Math. Hungar. or Studia Sci. Math. Hungar.?

Broader question: What is the best resource for investigating such questions? When a journal changes its name, how is a working mathematician to know?

Comment: mathscinet usually knows the current names and abbreviations, but you would have thought of that probably.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Mathscinet, the name of this journal was
A Magyar Tudományos Akadémia. Matematikai Kutató Intézetének Közleményei.

Abbreviation: Magyar Tud. Akad. Mat. Kutató Int. Közl.

It changed the name in 1977 and now is called Alkalmazott Matematikai Lapok.
But the paper you refer to is listed under the old name.

Comment: Thanks! Whom should I write to in order to suggest that the entry for Magyar Tud. Akad. Mat. Kutató Int. Közl. include “formerly Publ. Math. Institute Hung.“?

Comment: According to Mathscinet, "Publ. Math. Inst. Hung" never was the official name. There was only one change of name, the one I mentioned in my answer.